# Mixing TypeScript and Meteor - Classes across multiple files

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

Apologies for any incorrect terminology. For those not familiar with Meteor, [it has a well-defined order of script loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693113/how-do-i-change-the-order-in-which-meteor-loads-javascript-files). I'm trying to create many `*.ts` files containing a class, like you'd see in C#'s `*.cs` files. I want to reference these `*.ts` files between each other, and ultimately from a `main.ts`.

Compiling Car.ts:

```
class Car {
   constructor(public age: number) { }
}
```

Generates Car.js:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Car;
})();
```

With Meteor, I want the following output:

```
Car = (function () {
    function Car(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Car;
})();
```

So that Car can be referenced from another file, main.ts:

```
/// <reference path="car.ts"/>
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(Car); // Hopefully prints [Function: Car]
    var a: Car = null; // Compiles
});
```

I can get close by modifying Car.ts:

```
declare var Car;

class Car_ {
   constructor(public age: number) {}
}

Car = Car_;
```

But this produces a kludgy output:

```
var Car_ = (function () {
    function Car_(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Car_;
})();
Car = Car_;
```

And necessitates a kludgy main.ts:

```
/// <reference path="car.ts"/>
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(Car); // Prints [Function: Car_]
    var a: Car_ = new Car(); // Yuck!
});
```

Any advice? I might be treating this like too much like a C# application.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem... TS wraps everything in an IIFE, can't you just export `Car`?

Comment: I don't want to clutter the codebase with underscores under every other type token. In the above code, you have to write `var a: Car = new Car_()`which is pretty terrible. Ideally I'd be able to write something like `declare var Car = class Car {}`.

Comment: I'm aware of AMD/CommonJS modules but have struggled to find example codebases which also use Meteor (and after that, I'd want them to work on both client-side and server-side?).

Answer (score 1):

One solution involves setting the global object:

```
class Car {
   constructor(public age: number) {}
}

global.Car = Car;
```

which compiles to:

```
var Car = (function () {
    function Car(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Car;
})();
global.Car = Car;
```

I'm not very happy with this solution because `global` is a nodejs-specific thing and won't work in a browser, which uses `window`. It turns out `this` works both in-browser and on server:

```
class Car {
   constructor(public age: number) {}
}

this.Car = Car;
```

Compiles to:

```
 var Car = (function () {
    function Car(age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    return Car;
})();
this.Car = Car;
```

Inelegant, but better...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem yesterday. 
I was using [meteortypescript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteortypescript/compiler) , which was giving me the same kind of problems (it seems like it does not allow to work properly with packages).

I switched to another compiler script, and everything works fine now. 
Here it is : [mologie:typescript](https://atmospherejs.com/mologie/typescript), .

I did not look long for ways to solve the problem with the first one, but I stumbled upon a discussion between the authors of the two compiler plugins, that may explain some differences :
 https://github.com/mologie/meteor-typescript/issues/1

May be that will help

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this issue on my [blog](https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/meteor-typescript-classes-and-modules/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321467/using-modules-in-meteor-js-with-typescript). I decided to use the evil `eval` command, since it gave me the easiest possibility of using modules till something more sophisticated appears.

File `/lib/foo.ts`. It is positioned in the subdirectory since it has to be loaded before Bar as it is extending Foo.

```
eval('var Hugo = (this.Hugo || (this.Hugo = {})'); // this will override the automatically emitted var Hugo and assigns it with globally defined Hugo module 

module Hugo {
  export class Foo {
    foo():string {
      return 'foo'
    }
  }
}
```

File `/bar.ts`

```
/// <reference path="lib/foo.ts"/>
eval('var Hugo = (this.Hugo || (this.Hugo = {})'); // this will override the automatically emitted var Hugo and assigns it with globally defined Hugo module 

module Hugo {
 export class Bar extends Foo {
    bar () : string {
      return 'bar';
    }
  }
}
```

File `/test.ts`

```
/// <reference path="lib/foo.ts"/>
/// <reference path="bar.ts"/>

var m = new Hugo.Bar();
console.log(m.bar());
console.log(m.foo());
```

As mentioned before, for classes the solution is even simpler:

```
class ExportedClass {
    variable : int;
} 
this.ExportedClass = ExportedClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

scrap TS and Meteor would only run the .js files anyways.

Use https://atmospherejs.com/universe/modules instead.

Answer (score -1):

> I might be treating this like too much like a C# application.

Yes. Removing the `var` from `var Car` has no change in this particular case (both are global).

The following will work fine. Just move `car.ts` into a sub folder:

```
/// <reference path="./foo/car.ts"/>
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(Car); // Hopefully prints [Function: Car]
    var a: Car = null; // Compiles
});
```

Comment: I've pushed a barebones example here: https://github.com/ItzWarty/simplemeteor and am getting this error: http://puu.sh/gF9A2/954dc2b17c.png - I believe this is because Car.js's `var` makes the `Car` class at the script-block level, meaning it's not accessible to main.ts's context.